# Como é feita a relação do Java com o MySQL?

Tags: java, mysql

Estou querendo desenvolver um software de controle de despesas e quero utilizar JavaSwing com MySQL. Portanto tenho uma dúvida com relação ao banco de dados. Sei que ele fica em um servidor, mas quando eu compilar o programa e desejar distribuir o software eu terei de instalar um servidor em outras máquinas? O banco de dados vai junto com o programa? Não entendo como é feita essa relação do Java com o MySQL.

Comment: Isso não tem nada a ver com o JAVA. O MySQL é um produto à parte. Se quer usar MySQL, precisa instalar o MySQL em pelo menos UMA das máquinas da rede do cliente. Se não quer essa característica, pode escolher outra de infinitas maneiras de armazenar dados com java. Seria bom [edit] sua pergunta e ser mais claro no que você precisa realmente. Se for só 'conversar' sobre isso para se situar, seria melhor fazer uns pontinhos com perguntas mais específicas para poder participar do chat da rede.

Comment: Não que eu considere que essa seja uma das melhores perguntas do site, mas na minha opinião é perfeitamente válida. A menos que alguém me demonstre o contrário, discordo de quem vota para fechar ela.

Comment: Também não concordo com os downvotes. Por mais absurdo que possa parecer algum questionamento (principalmente pros grandes sábios do site), quem pergunta quer e precisa justamente de um esclarecimento.

Answer (score 1):

Quando você vai conectar o Java com o banco de dados (no caso MySQL), você tipicamente faz algo assim:

```
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(
        "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/basededados", "usuario", "senha");
```

Observe que no primeiro parâmetro você tem uma URL. Se nele, ao invés de você usar `localhost`, usar um IP ou nome de host, é lá que ele vai conectar. Assim sendo, você dá o local de rede onde está o banco de dados, e portanto o banco de dados não precisa estar na mesma máquina onde o seu programa Swing é executado. Esse comando só será executado quando o programa estiver em execução, nunca durante a compilação. Até porque pode ser que o usuário ou a seha, ou até mesmo a própria URL sejam lidas do usuário ou de algum arquivo de configuração.

Você compila o programa sem o banco de dados, apenas coloca no classpath ou modulepath o JAR necessário para conectar-se a ele em tempo de execução. Você não precisa do banco de dados para compilar o programa.

Pode até ser que faria sentido você instalar o MySQL na mesma máquina onde o programa em Swing rodaria. Mas se você precisar de duas ou mais máquinas acessando o mesmo banco de dados ao invés de banco de dados separados, ele só seria instalado em uma única máquina e acessado via IP ou hostname.

A [classe `DriverManager`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html) e a [interface `Connection`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html) estão no [pacote `java.sql`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/sql/package-summary.html). É esse o pacote que contém as classes e interfaces necessárias para que o seu programa possa utilizar algum banco de dados. No entanto, a conexão com o banco de dados mesmo é gerenciada pelo conector, que no caso do MySQL, pode ser baixado [**aqui**](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/). Em geral, para cada tipo de banco de dados diferente, você precisará de um conector específico diferente.

Comment: Achei válida a resposta. Não entendi os downvotes

Comment: Vou ser sincero, de primeira não entendi a resposta, aliais deu a entender, eu não vou negar que ainda acho que para o conhecimento do AP creio que vai soar confusa, eu creio que possivelmente seja necessário explicar para ele que dependendo do caso mysql nem seria o foco dele, depende do tipo de app, e se for um app para multiplos usuarios ou para uma loja por exemplo ai caberia explicar um pouco mais a comunicação da "rede". E voltando ao caso contrário seria explicar como trabalhar com um "banco local" (algo que seja voltado para trabalhar com local mesmo), eu não discordo da resposta...

Comment: ...só que de inicio não me pareceu a explicação suficiente para o que o ap precisa entender, acho a resposta promissora e que pode evoluir e terá o meu apoio nesse caso, só que não acho que os downvotes foram errados, o meu downvote eu removi já, eu ia comentar na hora mas estava um pouco ocupado, removi ele agora pq depois da edição a resposta já tem um "norte", mas acho que sinceramente o AP vai ter dificuldade e vc poderia considerar melhorar a resposta nos pontos que eu citei. Espero que leve em consideração tudo como uma sugestão para melhorar a postagem.

Comment: Eu já acho que quando se responde apenas o que foi perguntando é o suficiente. Um plus seria a critério de quem responde, alertando o usuário pra outras possibilidades para bancos de dados, critérios para escolha etc. Enriquece a resposta porém nem sempre é o que os que perguntam desejam.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Bem, eu acho que a resposta já cobre todos os pontos da pergunta. Se ele tiver uma dúvida do tipo "*como ou onde instalar o MySQL?*", aí eu já diria que o melhor é abrir uma outra pergunta. Se ele quiser esclarecimentos sobre o que fazer com o `Connection`, a mesma coisa e poderia apontar até um monte de outras perguntas neste site. No entanto, eu acrescentei mais algumas coisinhas que acho que já seriam o suficiente. Se ele (ou qualquer outra pessoa) tiver mais dúvidas quanto a minha resposta, basta postar um comentário.

Comment: @JoaoPaulo se olhar o [histórico da postagem](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/319411/revisions) vai ver que de início ela não respondia algumas coisas do que foi perguntado. Importante isso para contextualizar os comments anteriores.

Comment: Então no meu caso não seria necessariamente o MySQL, eu poderia usar um banco de dados local. Quais seriam as alternativas?

Comment: @DaniloFerrari Há diversos bancos de dados que você poderia utilizar: MySQL, MariaDB, PostgreSQL, Oracle, SQL Server, Firebird, H2, SQLite, Derby e mais um monte de outros, a lista é grande. É verdade que alguns deles como o SQL Server e o Oracle, são razoavelmente pesados e faria pouco sentido usá-los localmente, mas ainda assim isso é perfeitamente possível. No caso do MySQL, é perfeitamente possível em qualquer um dos casos.

Comment: @DaniloFerrari Mas se você já pensa em trocar o banco de dados, recomendaria o MariaDB. No entanto, isso é recomendação pessoal minha, vai ter gente que terá alguma opinião diferente.

Comment: Caro @DaniloFerrari creio que sim, seria interessante vc detalhar em que tipos de ambiente acredita que sua aplicação vai rodar, eu especulei um pouco e acho que por causa disso já dá para você entender melhor e até conseguir melhorar a sua pergunta, acho que o Victor já conseguiu dar um "norte" pra ti, vou aguardar, creio que vai ser possivel manter a pergunta aberta se fizer a tal melhoria.